# Automapper class in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Using AutoMapper class we can mapping db fields with Model's properties. 
I recently found one issue during mapping using AutoMapper class in ASP.NET/C# based MVC application.

Basically, I need to calculate Due Amount which is not coming from result set. Due Amount Calculated based on subtraction of Amount & Discount Amount. So for that I have added one property in Model (let's say 'DueAmount' which is not contains in result set) and tried to bind with Amount and Discount field but every time it's showing me null value for DueAmount.

e.g

```
Mapper.CreateMap<GetPostPaymentItems_Result, AvailCredit_OpenReceivables_Grid>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Item, origin => origin.MapFrom(src => src.EntityType + "</br>" + " " + src.EntityTypeID))
.ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerID, origin => origin.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerID + "</br>" + src.CustomerName))                           
.ForMember(dest => dest.Due,  origin => origin.MapFrom(src => Convert.ToDecimal(src.Amount - src.Discount)))
.ForMember(dest => dest.AllocationAuto, origin => origin.MapFrom(src => Convert.ToDecimal(src.Amount - src.Discount)));
```

If I did same thing with properties like 'CustomerID' or 'Item' which are coming from result set then it's working as expected and I can perform subtraction too.

Do you have any idea about how to map with property which is not coming from result set ?

Comment: If you inspect your source object before you map it, what are the values of `Amount` and `Discount`? What are their types?

Comment: public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
public decimal? Discount { get; set; }

Both datatypes are as decimal(allow null) as above.
and I got values 1 for Amount and 0 for Discount.